# Implicit super constructor Person() is undefined. Must explicitly invoke another constructor

Tags: java, class, object

Im receiving that error when trying create a constructor for the second class. Do I need to use the same parameters for the second class as the first class?

```
class Person {
    private String name;
    private String gender;
    private int phone;

    protected Person(String n, String g, int p)
            {name = n; gender = g; phone = p;} 
    public String toString(){return name +" "+gender+" "+phone;}
}


class Student extends Person { 
      private String subject;
      private int sNumber; 
      protected Student(String s, int sn){subject = s; sNumber = sn;} 
}


class Lecturer extends Person { 
  private String Department;
  private int staffNo;
  public Lecturer(String d, int stfNo){Department = d; staffNo = stfNo;}   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Every extended class calls the super constructor first. In your Person class you have defined only a non default constructor therefore there is no default constructor.

Either provide a default constructor (constructor without any parameters) in `Person` or call the super constructor explicitly with `super(name, gender, phone)`

Answer (score 0):

When compiled, your compiler will add `super()` as the first line of your childs constructor searching for the parent non arg constructor.

Since your parent class already has one using params, no default no arg constructor will be created at compile time.

Two solutions :

1. Add `super(string,string,int)` giving it the right parameters as the first line of your childs constructor
2. Create a `Person()` constructor taking no arguments so that `super()` finds something to call at compilation time.

Answer (score 0):

If a class extends another class, it must call the constructor of that extended class.

Since you specified a constructor for `Person` you need to call it in `Student` and `Lecturer` as the first statement:

```
protected Student(String s, int sn, String n, String g, int p)
{
    super(n, g, p);
    subject = s;
    sNumber = sn;
}
```

You might not have seen this error before, since the compiler automatically adds `super();` as the first statement. Since this constructor does not exists (you specified your own) this does not work.

If you don't call the constructor of the super class you never initialize it.